# In Google Chrome or other browsers, can requestAnimationFrame() be able to be pushed to higher repaint frequency?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

This is a somewhat advanced question about `requestAnimationFrame()`.

I think [the proper use of   as on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), is as follows:

That is, it is similar to a `setTimeout()`, say, when the screen will be repainted, tell me so that I can do something, in a way similar to, "when you are going to give a final exam, let me know so I can study and I don't want to study before that and waste my time".

So the code is:

```js
const elDisplay = document.querySelector("#display");

const startTime = Date.now();

let runCount = 0;

function updateData(timestamp) {
  runCount++;
  elDisplay.textContent = `${Date.now()}\n${timestamp}\n${(Date.now() - startTime) / 1000}\n${timestamp / 1000}\n${runCount}\n${runCount / (timestamp / 1000)}`;
  requestAnimationFrame(updateData);
}

requestAnimationFrame(updateData);
```

```css
#display {
  font: 21px Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

It is able to be called about 60 times per second, in line with the MDN docs.

When the program above runs, the last number is how many times the callback is invoked per second.

However, let's say it is either the improper use or the obsessive use of `requestAnimationFrame()`, as follows, I am able to get about 250 repaints per second. So what does that mean?  Does that mean `requestAnimationFrame()` can be pushed to a higher limit?  Especially, processors nowadays has 4 or 8 or 12 cores, and graphics cards are increasing power 2 times every 1.5 to 2 years, so maybe the number of repaints can be pushed.  I looked at the data and saw that the number of seconds elapsed is accurate, so it is not like an overflow of callbacks are being supplied to `requestAnimationFrame()` (that every callback is honored).

#### Version 2:

```js
const elDisplay = document.querySelector("#display");

const startTime = Date.now();

let runCount = 0;

function updateData(timestamp) {
  runCount++;
  elDisplay.textContent = `${Date.now()}\n${timestamp}\n${(Date.now() - startTime) / 1000}\n${timestamp / 1000}\n${runCount}\n${runCount / (timestamp / 1000)}`;
}

function makeRequest() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(updateData);
    makeRequest();
  }, 0);
}

makeRequest();
```

```css
#display {
  font: 21px Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

I was able to get about 200 updates per seconds. And if it is version 3 below, I can even get 250 updates on Google Chrome.  So what does that mean?  Does the mean `requestAnimationFrame()` can be pushed?  Or one thing I was suspecting was that, does that mean the screen is still repainting only at 60 times per second, but the fact that it was done 250 times per second, just means that there are 4 callbacks invoked and doing "unnecessary" update of the DOM, so out of those 4 updates of the DOM, really there is only 1 that is effectively shown on the screen? (That is, out of 240 calls to `requestAnimationFrame()`, for a group of 4 calls to `requestAnimationFrame()`, only 1 is really useful and the 3 earlier ones are wasted?) How does it really work?

#### Version 3:

```js
const elDisplay = document.querySelector("#display");

const startTime = Date.now();

let runCount = 0;

const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
  runCount++;
  requestAnimationFrame((timestamp) => {
    elDisplay.textContent = `${Date.now()}\n${timestamp}\n${(Date.now() - startTime) / 1000}\n${timestamp / 1000}\n${runCount}\n${runCount / (timestamp / 1000)}`;
  });
}, 1);
```

```css
#display {
  font: 21px Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Check out the JavaScript event loop, that will answer all your questions. I don't quite have enough time to write up a fill answer now, but here's great talk on the topic: https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0

Comment: Jake again... the Stopwatch hard way guy

Comment: I don't think you're actually getting more frames per second, just more calls to your function for a given frame. Calls to `requestAnimationFrame` are queued and run in sequence at the next available frame. All you're showing is that, on your machine, you're able to loop that particular code 3-4 times per frame.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify a bit, `requestAnimationFrame(fn)` is `setTimeout(fn, time_before_next_painting_frame)`.

This `time_before_next_painting_frame` is variable, if you call it twice with 1ms of delay, at second call it will be 1ms lower than at first call, and thus **both callbacks will get called at the same time, in the same painting frame**.

How this remaining time is determined depends on the system, but in most cases (all but iOS), it is based on the active monitor's refresh-rate: it will use the next VSync open event sent from the monitor to tell the event loop "this frame is a painting frame, execute all painting related stuff and requestAnimation callbacks".

So yes, **you can get a higher frame rate**: buy a new monitor with an higher refresh rate.

---

As to why your code is called at an higher frequency than your monitor's refresh rate, it's simply because you are scheduling a lot of calls to the exact same painting frame. There is no rAF rate in there since there is no rAF loop.

Comment: yes, I think I understand it better later on, that the DOM displayed / refreshed on screen only happen 60 times per second, so when we do the `requestAnimationFrame()`, it is like, "I only want to update the DOM right before you show it on screen so that I am not wasting any effort".  Is this true so far what I am describing?

Comment: There is one concern I have... looking at Jake's video, what if the hardware is about to update at 1:10:22.123 pm, so I think the `requestAnimationFrame()` callback might be invoked at 1:10:22.115 pm (or 1:10:22.121 pm?) . But what if the callback actually takes more than 7ms to perform, such as if it is painting a canvas or doing some complicated animations? Then we just "miss the boat" and now it is the next refresh cycle, isn't it true? But I guess we won't be "doing it 2, 3, 4 times" when the screen only refreshes it once

Comment: Not sure about your "not wasting any effort" analogy, it's really just "I want to execute a callback before the next paint". Regarding the long frame case, yes you may "miss the boat", if that happens the next frames will get delayed.

Comment: I think it is like: the browser's JS engine updates the DOM (just a structure) onto the page every 16.66 ms.  So if we. update the DOM 3 times within that 16.66ms, using setInterval(), that's fine. We can update and replace content all we want. It just never get displayed, so it is wasted effort.

Comment: I also watched the JSConf video... so it looks like if our callback is too long, then out of the 60 updates per second, 1 can be skipped, or if our callback is consistently too long, then it becomes 30 updates per second or 41 updates per second depending how how long your callback runs (and depends on how the browser implements it, whether they only do it right at the 1/60 second tick)

Comment: No, the JS engine tells the DOM to update synchronously, but the DOM has almost nothing to do with the matter here. What happens every painting frame is the ["update the rendering"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) step of the event-loop, which does include painting the page, and thus which makes changes by the DOM visible on the monitor. As to is it "wasted" or not I can't tell, it may be necessary by your code logic to have intermediate steps in your DOM updates, but that doesn't really matter much here.

Comment: And regarding the long frame, the one frames that are discarded are the ones that should have happen during the long frame. But no frame is really skipped, it's just that the event-loop is stuck busy by your callback, just like it could happen from outside of the rAF callbacks. Doing `setTimeout(lockTheEventLoopFor1s)` will have exactly the same effect as `requestAnimationFrame(lockTheEventLoopFor1s)`.

Comment: "the JS engine tells the DOM to update synchronously" are you saying this happens in the context of `requestAnimationFrame(fn)`?  If `fn` is supposed to be called at 010/1000 and 026/1000 of the second, and you update the DOM tree at 012/1000 and 017/1000 and then 021/1000 and then 025/1000, so isn't the 012/1000 and 017/1000 and 021/1000 update wasted? I guess if you don't worry about CPU work wasted and electricity wasted, it is not an issue.  This discussed wasted effort: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCi6AZMkxcU

Comment: I mean this has nothing to do with *rAF*. When you do `document.querySelector('bar').textContent = "foo"; document.querySelector('bar').textContent = "barbaz"` the DOM has been updated synchronously, wherever this line has been called from. If you don't need the state where the node's textContent is `"foo"`, then yes, it's wasted, but you might also have something between these two calls that required your code to have this intermediate value, for instance you might have needed to measure if the string `"foo"` did fit in there.

Comment: This we can't know, so we can't call it "wasted", and once again *rAF* has nothing to do with it. It doesn't prevent from writing bad code if that's your question. (and I begin to think I'm wasting more than CPU work in this thread...)

Comment: I think we usually use rAF when we need to constantly update the screen, such as a stopwatch, or some stock price or chart, whatever. So that's why I said if before it get shown on screen, if we update the time, price, or chart in the DOM tree twice, then the first time, it was wasted. If we don't care about it, we don't have to, but then we probably won't be using rAF either

Comment: You use rAF when you want to call a callback before the next paint refresh. Usually it's best for things that will change what's displayed in the page. If you call it multiple times during the same frame, multiple callbacks will get called before the next paint. That's it. I don't understand why you want this to be more complicated than that. If you need to call multiple callbacks in the same frame, you can, otherwise, don't.